# Создать файл в отсутствующей директории

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Допустим, есть некоторая директория `root`, и есть три варианта:

1) она полностью пустая

2) в ней есть дочерняя пустая директория `dir`

3) в `dir` есть файл `file.txt`

Каким образом из терминала можно (пере-)записать некоторый текст в `file.txt` в любом из трёх случаев?

(можно переформулировать, нужно что-то типа `echo "hello, i'm text" > ./dir/file.txt`, но так, чтобы все отсутствующие промежуточные директории создавались вместе с файлом)

Comment: `mkdir --parents "root/dir"`

Comment: @user7860670 да, но оно только для директорий, а как применить это для файлов, я не знаю :)

Comment: `mkdir -p root/dir; echo text >root/dir/file.txt`

Comment: `>` создает файл если его еще нет

Comment: В общем, да, я так и сделал, но это не совсем то, что я хотел - я хотел в скрипте не разделять путь к файлу на папку и файл, а сразу закидывать имя в команду и не думать. Но оно работает, так что ладно.

Comment: можно еще перейти на ps `"hello, i'm text" > $( new-item -force "./dir/file.txt" )`

Comment: или написать функцию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать функцию которая будет создавать структуру каталогов

```
function newfile() {
  mkdir -p $(dirname $1)
  echo $1
}

echo "hello, i'm text" > $(newfile ./dir/file.txt)
```

Comment: Если часть пути - это существующий файл?

Comment: получится соответствующая ошибка, как и должно быть "Файл существует"

Comment: выпадать в ошибку при ошибке - это нормально!

Comment: Да выдает предупреждение, что часть пути является файлом: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Not a directory`